how to change number from 17072e7 to 10720000
i want to display the gpu price from exponential form to decimal in Java springboot im using thymeleaf
enter image description here
            <h2>Pilih GPU</h2>
            <select id="gpu-select" onchange="updateStoreLink('gpu')">
                <option value="">Pilih GPU</option>
                <th:block th:each="gpu : ${gpus}">
                    <option 
                        th:value="${gpu.price}"
                        th:text="${gpu.name + ' - IDR ' + gpu.price}"
                        th:attr="data-link=${gpu.linkToko}, data-image=${gpu.imageUrl}">
                        GPU Name
                    </option>


Hello and welcome. See if the answers to this other question help.

You can use #numbers.formatInteger for this:
<h2>Pilih GPU</h2>
<select id="gpu-select" onchange="updateStoreLink('gpu')">
    <option value="">Pilih GPU</option>
    <option 
        th:each="gpu : ${gpus}"
        th:value="${#numbers.formatInteger(gpu.price, 0)}"
        th:text="${gpu.name + ' - IDR ' + #numbers.formatInteger(gpu.price, 0)}"
        th:attr="data-link=${gpu.linkToko}, data-image=${gpu.imageUrl}">
        GPU Name
    </option>

Also, no need for the <th:block />.  Put your th:each directly in the <option>.

thank for the help
